# A href link on vue router-link

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have some dynamically-rendered text on a `router-link` component. The code is like this:

```html
<router-link :to="object.link" tag="div">
  <span v-html="object.text"/>
</router-link>
```

```js
object: {
  link: "home",
  text: "Click here to go to my homepage. Don't want that? Go to <a href="google.com">Google</a> instead."
}
```

Clicking the `div`/`router-link` will, as expected, navigate to the object's link. However, clicking the anchor word "Google" will navigate to the object's link as well instead of the intended `href`.

I'd like the behavior to be:

- click on the `div` or the text -> navigate to the object link
- click on the `a` tag -> navigate to the `a` reference

I can achieve the second by stopping click propagation on the `span`, but then clicking on the non `a`-tag text doesn't activate the `router-link`.
How can I achieve both of these behaviors?

Comment: Stopping propagation on the span [works for me](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/MWYyGdy). What are you doing differently?

Comment: The if(e.target.tagName) was what I needed! Thank you so much. If you'd like to add that as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Great. Happy it worked for you! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply a `click`-handler on the `span` wrapper that invokes [`Event.stopPropagation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) for `a` event targets:

```html
<template>
  <router-link :to="object.link" tag="div">
    <span @click="onWrapperClick" v-html="object.text" />
  </router-link>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  //...
  methods: {
    onWrapperClick(e) {
      if (e.target.tagName === 'A') {
        e.stopPropagation()
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

```js
const Home = {
  template: '#home'
}

const LinkDemo = {
  template: '#linkDemo',
  data() {
    return {
      object: {
        link: '/',
        text: `Click here to go to my homepage. Don't want that? Go to <a href="https://stackoverflow.com">StackOverflow</a> instead.`
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onWrapperClick(e) {
      if (e.target.tagName === 'A') {
        e.stopPropagation()
      }
    }
  }
};

const routes = [
  { path: '', component: Home },
  { path: '/demo', component: LinkDemo }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes
});

new Vue({
  router
}).$mount('#app');
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router@3.1.3"></script>

<script type="text/x-template" id="home">
    <div>
        <h2>Home</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <router-link to="/demo">External Link Demo</router-link>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-template" id="linkDemo">
    <div>
        <h2>External Link Demo</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <router-link :to="object.link" tag="div">
                  <span @click="onWrapperClick" v-html="object.text" />
                </router-link>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</script>

<div id="app">
    <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```